# Matching an exact element within geojson file parameters Openlayer 3

Tags: for-loop, openlayers-3

I have the following function that gets an option from a select and match it through the parameters within my geojson file. If the exact match is found, then the layer should be displayed with a specific style.

Everythng seems ok, since the function finds for each feature the proper object, it actually gets the string named "Criteria" and puts it in an array including all the criteria (ex. array = {"A", "B", "Bi", "Bii"}. It also checks if the selected option matches one of the elements within the array. However it doesn't output the command `setStyle`.

Any suggestions? A complete plunker can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7GuSZ6D51Q2WgmSEPWeX?p=info).

```
//when clicking the select
document.getElementById("criteria_select").addEventListener('click', function (){

//first step it loads the vector layer and sets the style to transparent
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < layers_group.length; ++i){
        layers_group[i].setStyle(transparentStyle);
        layers_group[i].setVisible(true);
    };
//second step when the select changes (i.e. I make a choice)
    $("#criteria_select").change(function() {
//it starts the function to change styles according to the selection made
        var selectedCriteria = $("#criteria_select").val();
        console.log('selectedCriteria',selectedCriteria);
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < source_group.length; index++){
            source_group[index].forEachFeature(function(feat){

                var array = feat.get('Criteria').split(',');
                    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    {
                        console.log(array[i]);
                        if (selectedCriteria === array[i]){

                            feat.setStyle(selectStyle);

                            } else {
                            //and if doesnt exist switch back to the deafult style
                            feat.setStyle(transparentStyle);
                            }
                    }
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plunkr code is full of errors.

1. **search_criteria.js** script is loaded with wrong url.
2. There is no **transparentStyle** object defined anywhere in the code.
3. The 2 `ol.style` objects defined are inside init() method so cannot be used outside.
4. Both `ol.style` objects are same.
5. The url parameter while creating `ol.source.Vector` is wrong. Because of this none of the vector layer is loaded at all.

I guess your working code wont be having above errors. I have taken liberty to fix above issues and added **transparentStyle** object.

The main issue is in your for-loop. Instead of checking if criteria array contains selectedCriteria you are comparing each criteria value with selectedCriteria. Break the loop when if condition is evaluated to true.

**Edit 1:**

```
if (selectedCriteria === array[i].trim()){
        feat.setStyle(selectStyle);
        break;
} else {
    //and if doesnt exist switch back to the deafult style
    feat.setStyle(defaultStyle);
}
```

I have updated the code in this plunkr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/PCz1GOltEWVOWelH6Rqq?p=preview)

`if (selectedCriteria === array[i])` is working correctly. But the value you are passing in array[i] contains wrong value. If you see your **mediterranean.geojson**  file criteria property values are like **"A, Bii, Ciii, Dii"** there is extra space between 2 comma separated values. Because of this extra space you might be getting these issues.
Fix :
Trim the String before comparing. I have updated the Code in Plunckr and in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Sumanth, you are right: I copied in the plunker just few files from a more complex work and I did some errors in writing it. Your suggestion seems working but not in the way I want. Actually, the categories to search for are A, B, Bi, Bii etc. I updated the plunker to make some trials. If I search for Bi, for example, it loads both Bi and B. My need is to match the exact code. I thought that the condition if (selectedCriteria === array[i]) did the work in matching the exact word, but it doesn't.